# socket.io communication between nodejs scripts

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to setup some socket.io communications, the communication between my server (app.js)(runs on a raspberry pi) and a website(public/index.html) works fine. Now I want to expand it so when my app.js receives a call from index.html it emits it further to another node.js script(bed.js) that will run on another raspberry pi. I tried to use the npm module socket.io-client, but this can only receive apparently

!edit! problem has narrowed down to the setrgb part, there it won't emit.

!edit 2! when i receive setRGB, i emit setRGBclient, but that can only be received in bed.js, not in index.html, there lays my problem, i need to share the connections or force it to another connection, no clue how i fix it though

APP.JS:

```
let http = require('http').createServer(handler); //require http server, and create server with function handler()
let fs = require('fs'); //require filesystem module
let io = require('socket.io')(http) //require socket.io module and pass the http object (server)
let delay = require('delay');
console.log('Define each color from RGB Strip light.');
http.listen(8080); //listen to port 8080


function handler (req, res) { //create server
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function(err, data) { //read file index.html in public folder
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //display 404 on error
            return res.end("404 Not Found");
        }
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //write HTML
        res.write(data); //write data from index.html
        return res.end();
    });
}
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {// WebSocket Connection

    socket.on("test", function(){
        console.log("sampletext");
    });


    socket.on("setRGB", function(data){
        socket.emit("setRGBClient", data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

bed.js:

```
let socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8080');

let lightstate = false;
let stayOff = false;
let fadeState = false;
console.log("check");
socket.emit("test");
socket.on("setRGBClient" ,function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can just broadcast setRGBClient.

```
   socket.broadcast.emit("setRGBClient", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a learning exercise. Otherwise I’d caution against socket.io for such applications.

However I can only see the subscription for ‘setRGB’ not the emit-part.

Comment: the emit part for setRGB is in the index.html, that works, it logs "data", but it does not emit setRGBClient. What would you use otherwise?

Comment: Personally I'd have API endpoint at the website and letting the PIs poll RGB-settings. While it seems counter-intuitive but makes sense in terms of security and networking. Socket-io builds on top of web sockets, short/long polling, but will have a massive impact on the API and will require more code to start.

Comment: ah i see what you mean, yes ofcourse i would do this if it was made for production, this is just something i will use at home, myself.